# alternative of 'getElementById' in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Check this [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/Odm16CqfgIeAivF2Z94x?p=preview), i have one list with id `myMenuList`, this id am accessing in `script.js` to display `Numer of li` and `UL width` by `$scope.mml = angular.element(document.getElementById('myMenuList'));`.
But as per requirement I should not be accessing it in controller like this. Is there any alternative we can do by keeping the same behaviour?

**HTML CODE**

```
  <div class="menucontainer left">
   <ul id="myMenuList" ng-style="myStyle">
     <li ng-repeat="item in items"> <a href="#">{{item.name}}</a>        </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $scope.mml = angular.element(document.getElementById('myMenuList'));
 $timeout(function() {
   $scope.numerofli = $scope.mml.find('li').length;
    $scope.ulwidth = $scope.mml[0].clientWidth;
 }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3USFbokybDie1YTmODwG?p=preview)

Implement a directive with isolated scope to encourage modularity and re-use:

```
app.directive('myMenuList', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { 
      myMenuList: '='
    },
    link:function($scope, $element, $attr) {
      $timeout(function(){
          $scope.myMenuList.numerofli= $element.find('li').length  ;
          $scope.myMenuList.ulwidth= $element[0].clientWidth;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
});
```

To use it, initialize an output model from inside your parent controller:

```
app.controller('scrollController', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.output = {};
  ...
});
```

Place the `my-menu-list` attribute on the `ul` element, and pass it the model defined earlier:

```
  <ul my-menu-list="output" ng-style="myStyle">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items"> <a href="#">{{item.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

When the directive executes it will populate the model with two properties, which you can then reference in your HTML:

```
<p><b>Numer of 'li': {{output.numerofli}}</b></p>
<p><b>Width: {{output.ulwidth}}</b></p>
```

Comment: Instead of creating an isolated scope, you can also use the `$parse` service to mitigate the watchers created by the isolate scopes.

Answer (score 10):

Use only

```
 var ele = angular.element('#id');
 var ulwidth = ele[0].clientWidth;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use query selector

```
 angular.element( document.querySelector( '#id' ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers might be correct on the alternative of `getElementById`, your code should be rewritten in the Angular-way. See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/41i9XVuZJklUwTpAEGjR?p=preview).

It should reflect your requirements anyway.