# Convert Javascript function to AngularJS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I wrote a simple javascript function that switches between two div elements. Like so:

```
function goToResults() {
    document.getElementById("services").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("results").style.display = "block";
}
```

As I am learning Angular, I want to convert that to an Angular function in app.js. Can I do the following?

```
$scope.goToResults = function () {
    $scope.getElementById("services").style.display = "none";
    $scope.getElementById("results").style.display = "block";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use directives for DOM manipulation. Check [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Comment: Please review all the core directives in left menu of documentation. There are numerous ones available to do this ... `ng-style` ... `ng-class` ... `ng-if` .. `ng-show` ... `ng-hide` ... `ng-switch` .... all are driven by your data model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with the piece of code that you provided.

Firstly there are no such thing as AngularJS only functions. They are the same as any other javascript function. If you want to use a "javascript" function inside AngularJS's scope, you can do the following:

```
function goToResults() {
   ...
}

$scope.goToResults = goToResults;
```

Secondly, it's considered a bad practice to handle DOM manipulation inside a controller. Use directives instead.

Thirdly, from what I understand you want to show or hide a div based on some event. There are some in-built features that do that exact thing (ng-show, ng-hide, ng-if).

You seem to lack some fundamental knowledge about Javascript & AngularJS, and I'd suggest going through the tutorials given example by Angular's own documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: yes I am relatively new to AngularJS, I will look through the tutorials some more

Comment: AngularJS has one of the biggest communities from the whole javascript ecosystem, there are a lot of good tutorials out there. You can also search on youtube for some end-to-end tutorial. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

It's technically possible to use

```
$scope.goToResults = function () {
    document.getElementById("services").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("results").style.display = "block";
}
```

However, this isn't a very 'angular' way of doing this. A more 'angular' route is described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738234/alternative-of-getelementbyid-in-angularjs). Generally speaking, referring to specific elements isn't the 'angular' way; it seeks to instead have a set of javascript utilities readily available for the (processed) HTML to use, such as directives, which are essentially new elements or attributes for use in HTML. The implementation of the directives has no direct coupling to the elements it modifies with the use of those attributes or elements, which makes angular much more reusable and, in my and many others' opinions, easier to read and write once you get used to it.

Comment: *"The most immediately correct way"* ... no it's not

Comment: Does it not work? I was clear that it's bad practice to do so, but it is the way of doing it most similar to the OP, is it not? (other than just plain JS, but then it isn't a suitable answer)

Comment: So why would you offer a first solution that is bad practice and state that it is *"correct"*. Look at your own answer and read nothing but the first line and the code

Comment: It *is* correct; it's just bad practice. You yourself called it a 'solution'. I've edited it to be more clear about its being a kluge.